# 勝手で pitch accent

Tags: pitch-accent

I have always heard 勝手 and 勝手に pronounced as 平板. When preceded by another noun forming a compound 勝手 does seem to become 頭高, but I have recently come across 勝手で, standalone, pronounced as 頭高. Did I hear it right? [(1)](https://youtu.be/cdzAZ4rYT3U?t=230), [(2)](https://youtu.be/KGdtewmeWkg?t=177), [(3)](https://youtu.be/imLcz7TE3fc) 平板 also seems to be common for 勝手で. Does the 平板 pronunciation apply only to 勝手で? What about 勝手に, 勝手な, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you linked is pronounced heiban, so you heard it wrong all three times. And re: your further question, 勝手 is always heiban.

Maybe try using this [word + particle perception test](https://kotu.io/tests/pitchAccent/perception/words?mode=mora&particlesOnly=true) to improve your ability to differentiate heiban and odaka.

Comment: Seems like particles can always successfully mess up my hearing.

Comment: 勝手 is atamadaka when used as a suffix (使い勝手, 好き勝手, etc.)